# Как наложить изображения в C#?

Tags: c#, графика, изображения, visual-studio, png

Имеется PictureBox, в него загружено фоновое изображение. Нужно добавить еще несколько изображений поверх, причем они не должны полностью перекрывать фон. Все изображения в формате .png, на них изображены различные геометрические фигуры черным цветом, остальное пространство - это прозрачный фон.  Все картинки одинакового размера.
По сути, мне нужно реализовать возможность показа различных слоев как в графических редакторах.
Пока никаких идей =(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможно вам подойдет такой вариант. Наложить один PictureBox на другой.
Разместите на форме pictureBox1, добавьте в загрузку формы код:

```
        // создаем слой
        PictureBox pictureBox2 = new PictureBox
        {
            // задаем размер контейнера, как у родительского контейнера
            Size = pictureBox1.Size,
            // можно управлять положением слоя, относительно родительского контейнера
            Location = new Point(0, 0), 
            // задаем прозрачность фону
            BackColor = Color.Transparent,
            // изображение слоя
            Image = Resources.neddedImage 
        };

        // добавляем слой в родительский контейнер
        pictureBox1.Controls.Add(pictureBox2);
```

---

Вот вам другой пример. Погуглил, нашел функцию, которая вам подойдет, немного изменил.

```
    public static Bitmap CombineBitmap(IEnumerable<string> files)
    {
        //read all images into memory
        List<Bitmap> images = new List<Bitmap>();
        Bitmap finalImage = null;

        try
        {
            int width = 0;
            int height = 0;

            foreach(string image in files)
            {
                // create a Bitmap from the file and add it to the list
                Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image);

                // update the size of the final bitmap
                width += bitmap.Width;
                height = bitmap.Height > height ? bitmap.Height : height;

                images.Add(bitmap);
            }

            // create a bitmap to hold the combined image
            finalImage = new Bitmap(width, height);

            // get a graphics object from the image so we can draw on it
            using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(finalImage))
            {
                // set background color
                g.Clear(Color.Transparent);

                // go through each image and draw it on the final image
                foreach(Bitmap image in images)
                {
                    g.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height));
                }
            }

            return finalImage;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            if(finalImage != null) finalImage.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            // clean up memory
            foreach(Bitmap image in images)
            {
                image.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

На кнопку или загрузку формы:

```
        // объединяем картинки
        Bitmap bitmap = CombineBitmap(new[] { @"a:\1.png", @"a:\2.png" });

        // загружаем результат в PictureBox
        pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;

        // сохраняем в файл
        bitmap.Save(@"a:\3.png");
```

Я протестировал, все работает как вам надо. Юзайте гугл ;)

Comment: Эх.. забыл добавить, что еще и сохранять нужно. 
А ваш пример в визуальном плане вполне устраивает, но сохранить как единое целое таким способом, я так понимаю, нельзя.

Comment: @PastoriXx: А вот уж сливать слои вам придётся вручную. Фотошоп за вас никто не напишет.

Comment: пути только поправьте :)

Comment: А как поменять месторасположения 2.png? Что-то не могу разобраться.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы динамически создал PictureBox под каждое изображение,
установил свойство pictureBox.BackColor = Color.Transparen, 
порядок отображения на форме контролировал с помощью методов BringToFront(), SendToBack().